# FontAwesome 5 icons not showing in React App

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome inside a React App and TypesScript(created with react-react-app), but the icons aren't showing yet I followed the documentation's guide step-by-step.

**Importing icons globally (index.tsx)**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faCheckSquare, faCoffee);
```

**Using the icons in my component**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

export const Home = ()=> {
return  <FontAwesomeIcon icon='coffee' size='lg'/>
}
```

**What is happening?**

The below screenshot shows where the icon is supposed to be next to **view price changes**  but it's not visible. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most probably Css of font-awesome is not added
try adding this in your index.html file.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">    
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: It doesn't work too even though I had version 5 CDN. By the way, this seems like version 4 whereas the npm packages I Installed is version 5

Comment: can you try adding inline css to increase the size of icons ? it will help to confirm the problem

Comment: What do you mean @Sahil?